# Updating pexif info?

Tags: python-2.7

I tried to use pexif to update my photo EXIF with following the work on StackExchange ([How to save geodatabase attachments to disk with updated exif data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84763/how-to-save-geodatabase-attachments-to-disk-with-updated-exif-data)). However, I got the below error message when I used pexif.JpegFile.fromFile for it.

How do I resolve it?

```
> img = pexif.JpegFile.fromFile('IOP_002.jpg')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    img = pexif.JpegFile.fromFile('IOP_002.jpg')
  File "C:\Ernie_Liu\EXIF_extraction\pexif-0.13\pexif.py", line 944, in fromFile
    return JpegFile(open(filename, "rb"), filename=filename, mode=mode)
  File "C:\Ernie_Liu\EXIF_extraction\pexif-0.13\pexif.py", line 1003, in __init__
    attempt = segment_class(mark, input, data, self.mode)
  File "C:\Ernie_Liu\EXIF_extraction\pexif-0.13\pexif.py", line 801, in __init__
    DefaultSegment.__init__(self, marker, fd, data, mode)
  File "C:\Ernie_Liu\EXIF_extraction\pexif-0.13\pexif.py", line 143, in __init__
    self.parse_data(data)
  File "C:\Ernie_Liu\EXIF_extraction\pexif-0.13\pexif.py", line 845, in parse_data
    ifd = IfdTIFF(self.e, offset, self, self.mode, tiff_data)
  File "C:\Ernie_Liu\EXIF_extraction\pexif-0.13\pexif.py", line 421, in __init__
    self.special_handler(tag, actual_data)
  File "C:\Ernie_Liu\EXIF_extraction\pexif-0.13\pexif.py", line 749, in special_handler
    if self.tags[tag][1] == "Make":
KeyError: 50341
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem and after a short, pyhton-novice look into the source code of pexif.py, I concluded that the file is not supported. As far as I could tell, the library supports only some types of jpeg formats and it does not seem to be maintained anymore.

I know this wasn't what you wanted to hear, and I actually hope I am mistaking about this, but you might want to search for other ways of accomplishing your task. I've been looking into exiftool and seems it does what I want (add 7hours to the date taken on a set of pics) in a single command-line, even though I would have liked to do it myself in python.